# EF model not updated in azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, database-first

I have set up a working asp.net mvc6 web-app in azure using an SQL database and EF (db-first). Everything worked fine untill I added some columns and tables to the database. After regenerating the model everything still works fine on my local machine, but after publishing the app and updating the database in azure (using SQLAzureMW) the new columns do not seem to exist in the model, because I get the error "invalid column name" for 10 columns. The pages that are using unaltered tables are still working

I checked my connectionstrings in the remote view of my Web.config file after connecting to my azure account in visual studio and they seem fine to me:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=tcp:      <hidden>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=datatheek7;User ID=<hidden>;Password=<hidden>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


<add name="datatheek7Entities" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.datatheek7Entities.csdl|res://*/Models    .datatheek7Entities.ssdl|res://*/Models.datatheek7Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:<hidden>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=datatheek7;User ID=<hidden>;Password=<hidden>;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Also the newly added columns and tables are visible when I connect to the database on azure in SSMS and I can see the correct edmx.diagram file in the models folder in azure. I that folder I also saw another edmx.diagram with the name of the project (in my case datatheek2.edmx.diagram). Because I suspected the application to still use that initial edmx diagram I just deleted it, but it didn't make any difference.

Anybody any idea's? It would be much appreciated!

For clarity the complete stack trace added below (excuse my formatting):

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'SignalsComplete'.
>   Invalid column name 'AmountWMG'. Invalid column name
>   'PrescriptionsCheckedBy'. Invalid column name
>   'PrescriptionsSubmitUserId'. Invalid column name
>   'PrescriptionsSubmitDate'. Invalid column name 'SignalsComplete'.
>   Invalid column name 'TimeUntill'. Invalid column name
>   'SignalsCheckedBy'. Invalid column name 'SignalsSubmitUserId'. Invalid
>   column name 'SignalsSubmitDate'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2418094
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>       +5694436    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +379
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2064
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +375
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +240
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>       +12    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand
>   t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +9
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +356
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +166
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>       +12    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +37
>
> ```
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for
> ```
>
> details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +744
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>       +109    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>       +142    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +279
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>       +11    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>
>   datatheek2.Controllers.BatchesController.Index() in
>   C:\Users\Arne\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\datatheek2\datatheek2\Controllers\BatchesController.cs:45
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>       +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>       +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>       +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +44
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +55
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>       +545    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly how you updated the Azure database?  I'm not clear how this was done.

Comment: I used the SQLdatabase migration wizard ( https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ ) it let's me select the tables I wish to update and then adds them to the database and when I checked the tables in SSMS they were there including all relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem!
I added some more testtables to the database locally and updated the model, then published again to azure. Those tables were shown perfectly fine in the associated views, so the model did update and the problem should be in the database schema. I extracted the complete db in SSMS and it seemed there were some difference in the version I published on azure and the one I had locally, really don't know why. After deleting the complete db in azure and publishing the local version everything worked.